# How to pass Integer wrapper class to a method in java?

Tags: java, methods, parameters, reference

Ex in java:

```
class A {
    private Integer x = new Integer(0);

    public void setValue(Integer q) {
        q = 20;
    }

    public void callX() {
       setValue(x);        // this does not set x to be 20, which is what i need. Is there a way?
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You cannot.

Wrapper types are immutable, therefore they effectively emulate behaviour of primitive types: by executing `q = 20` you make parameter `q` point to the new intstance of `Integer` with value `20`, but it doesn't change the original instance referenced by `x` in the calling method.

Comment: @tsubasa: What's exactly the problem?

Comment: Also, the Integer objects holding the values -128 to 127 are cached, so no duplicate wrapper objects are created.

Answer (score 8):

You could use `AtomicInteger` instead, it's mutable:

```
private AtomicInteger x = new AtomicInteger(0);

public void setValue(AtomicInteger q) {
    q.set(20);
}

public void callX() {
    setValue(x);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Java this behaviour would be considered very confusing. generally a setter, like setValue takes a value and does not alter its arguments.  A getter typically is used to return a value.

BTW: IMHO Don't use wrappers unless you have a good reason to do so.

Instead you might do something like this.

```
class A {
 public int getValue() {
    return 20;
 }

 public void callX() {
   int x = getValue(); // this sets x to be 20.
 }
}
```